# Calling view flipper in another activity?

Tags: android

I am having 2 activities, in each activity I am having a view-flipper and button. When the button in 1st activity is clicked, I want to view the 2nd activity's view-flipper child. How to do that? Is that Possible? If yes, please tell me how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just open the second activity (as well as child `viewFlipper`) on button click?

Comment: i can open 2nd activity by using the Intent, but couldn't able to view the child of view-flipper in 2nd activity @tahsinRupam

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly interact with views between activities. Instead, you should pass data in an `Intent` when you call `startActivity()` from the first activity. The data should tell the second activity which view to start with. For example, you can send the name or index of the view. You can learn more about sending data in an `Intent` from the official Android documentation.